# django Queryset exclude() multiple data

Tags: django

i have database scheme like this.

```
# periode
+------+--------------+--------------+
| id   | from         | to           |
+------+--------------+--------------+
| 1    | 2018-04-12   | 2018-05-11   |
| 2    | 2018-05-12   | 2018-06-11   |
+------+--------------+--------------+

# foo
+------+---------+
| id   | name    |
+------+---------+
| 1    | John    |
| 2    | Doe     |
| 3    | Trodi   |
| 4    | son     |
| 5    | Alex    |
+------+---------+

#bar
+------+---------------+--------------+
| id   | employee_id   | periode_id   |
+------+---------------+--------------+
| 1    | 1             |1             |
| 2    | 2             |1             |
| 3    | 1             |2             |
| 4    | 3             |1             |
+------+---------------+--------------+
```

I need to show `employee` that not in `salary`.

for now I do like this

```
queryset=Bar.objects.all().filter(periode_id=1)
result=Foo.objects.exclude(id=queryset)
```

but its fail, how do filter employee list not in salary?...

Comment: What is the Django model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well here you basically want the `foo`s such that there is no `period_id=1` in the `Bar` table.

We can let this work with:

```
ex = Bar.objects.all().filter(periode_id=1).values_list('employee_id', flat=True)
result=Foo.objects.exclude(id__in=ex)
```

Comment: for multiple value use ***__in*** ?... ah got it. lelt me try.

Comment: @BudiGunawan: yes, if it is an iterable at the right side, you need `__in` (unless of course you want to let it do other magic).